# how to pass selected value in ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax, selected, dropdown

Here is my code of html, ajax and php.  The value returned by selected is to be passed in php

I want to use these four selected value (bank, state, district and city) in text form (bank_name, state_name, district_name, city_name) in my php file to show the data based on these value.  If I use $bank=$_POST['bank[1]']; it gives the bank_id and so on, not the bank_name which was selected

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Dynamic Dependent Select Box using jQuery and PHP</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $(".state").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_district.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".district").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });

  $(".state").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_city.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".city").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });

});
</script>
<style>
label
{
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px;
}
div
{
 margin-top:100px;
}
select
{
 width:200px;
 height:35px;
}
</style>
</head>
<form name="frm_ifsc" method="post" action="show_ifsc.php">
<body>
<center>
<div>

<label>Bank:</label> 
<select name="bank" class="bank">
<option selected="selected">--Select Bank--</option>
<?php
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_banks");
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['bank_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['bank_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
 } 
?>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<label>State:</label> 
<select name="state" class="state">
<option selected="selected">--Select State--</option>
<?php
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_state");
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['state_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['state_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
 } 
?>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label>District:</label> <select name="district" class="district">
<option selected="selected">--Select District--</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>


<label>City:</label> <select name="city" class="city">
<option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>
<br />
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btnRegister">
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this a number of ways. I think the two easiest are:

**Modify JavaScript to get option text:**

```
var id = $( this ).html();
var dataString = "id=" + id;
```

**Modify select HTML:**

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['bank_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['bank_name']; ?></option>
```

Good luck!

Comment: next dropdown list is dependent on the bank_id, and so next dependable dropdown based on bank_id does not work

Comment: if one filed shows bank name and second field shows the url address, how to go to that url by selecting the bank name